# Recyclerview in fragment inside a viewpager

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, android-viewpager, fragment

I wanted to use recyclerview inside a fragment of my 3 fragment viewpager. I wrote the code and it ran perfectly but I don't know why it is too slow.When I swap from one fragment to another it almost takes half minute.Don't know what mistakes I did here.

Main Activity

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private Toolbar toolbar;
    private TabLayout tabLayout;
    private ViewPager viewPager;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        toolbar = (Toolbar)findViewById(R.id.toolBar);
        tabLayout = (TabLayout)findViewById(R.id.tabs);
        viewPager = (ViewPager)findViewById(R.id.viewPager);

        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        ViewPagerAdapter viewPagerAdapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
        viewPagerAdapter.addFragment(new OneFragment(), "One");
        viewPagerAdapter.addFragment(new TwoFragment(), "Two");
        viewPagerAdapter.addFragment(new ThreeFragment(), "Three");

        viewPager.setAdapter(viewPagerAdapter);
        tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);

    }
}
```

Here it is one of my fragment where I tried to implement recyclerview.

Fragment

```
public class TwoFragment extends Fragment {

    public TwoFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View view =  inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_two, container, false);

        OurData ourData = new OurData();
        ourData.pic.add(R.drawable.b);
        ourData.title.add("Hello");
        RecyclerView recyclerView = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.listRecyclerView);
        ListAdapter listAdapter = new ListAdapter();
        recyclerView.setAdapter((listAdapter));
        RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);

        return view;
    }
}

public class ListAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter {

    @Override
    public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.list_item, parent, false);
        return new ListViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        ((ListViewHolder) holder).bindView(position);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return OurData.title.size();
    }

    private class ListViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {
        private TextView text;
        private ImageView image;

        public ListViewHolder(View itemview) {
            super(itemview);
            text = (TextView) itemview.findViewById(R.id.textF);
            image = (ImageView) itemview.findViewById(R.id.imageF);
            itemview.setOnClickListener(this);
        }

        public void bindView(int position) {
            text.setText(OurData.title.get(position));
            image.setImageResource(OurData.pic.get(position));
        }

        public void onClick(View view) {

        }
    }
}

public class OurData {

    public static ArrayList<String> title = new ArrayList<String>();
    public static ArrayList<Integer> pic = new ArrayList<Integer>();

}
```

It tooks my whole day thinking what I did wrong. Please help me out!

Answer (score 0):

set your adapter `recyclerView.setAdapter((listAdapter));`
insise onViewCreated instead of onCreateView

Comment: Problem was in my resource.Images size were too big.Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is because of one of your Methods.
maybe 'OurData'
and also are you sure of this:

```
 @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return OurData.title.size();
    }
```

also try using Log in each code and see the part that takes time especially 'OurData'

Comment: Solved now.Problem was in my resources.images size were too big.Thanks